# i m not getting any suggestion for my name while adding my role in key vault , what should i do?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, secret-key

**i m not getting any suggestion for my name while adding my role in key vault , what should i do ?**
from here I m trying to add the role , as key vault administrator, to create a secret key in azure key vault

[image]

here when I m searching for my name it is showing me "no suggestions".

[image]
can anyone please help me, do I need to provide any more access? I logged in with the same mail id too,

Answer (score 0):

As you are **guest user** of the tenant, you won’t get suggestions while assigning roles.

When I tried to assign **`Key Vault Administrator`** by signing in with **guest user account**, I got same screen as you like below:

[image]

> You can only see the users if you enter their **full name** or
> **complete email address** in search bar as you are **guest user**.

When I entered my **entire email address** of guest user account in search bar, I can see the user like below:

[image]

I tried with **full username** of guest user account and able to find user like below:

[image]

After assigning the role, I’m able to **create secret** successfully with **guest** user account like below:

[image]

In your case, make sure to search with **entire email address** or your **full username** as you are guest user in that tenant.